# A false CLang warning: lambda capture 'this' is not used [-Wunused-lambda-capture]

Tags: android-ndk, clang

With Android CLang 17.0.2 from NDK 26.0.10792818 I get the following warning

```
warning: lambda capture 'this' is not used [-Wunused-lambda-capture]
```

in the code below:

```
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
constexpr bool is_specialization_v = is_specialization<Test, Ref>::value;

template <typename... Args, typename Func, std::size_t... index>
constexpr void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, const Func& f, std::index_sequence<index...>)
{
    (f(std::get<index>(t)), ...);
}

template <typename... Args, typename Func>
constexpr void for_each(const std::tuple<Args...>& t, const Func& f)
{
    for_each(t, f, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}

class TestReader
{
public:

    template<class Struct>
    void ReadV(Struct& val) const
    {
        if constexpr (is_specialization_v<Struct, std::tuple>)
        {
            for_each(val, [this](auto& field)
            {
                //Warining with Android CLang 17.0.2 from NDK 26.0.10792818:
                //lambda capture 'this' is not used [-Wunused-lambda-capture]
                ReadV(field);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            static_cast<void>(val);
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    TestReader reader;

    std::tuple<int> a(1);
    reader.ReadV(a);

    return 0;
}
```

if I replace `ReadV(field);` with `this->ReadV(field);` the code compiles without warnings.

Is it a compiler bug? Where to report it?